# Java Swing Repaint While Dragging Mouse

Tags: java, swing, drawing, mouseevent

I'm having difficulty getting a custom panel to repaint itself while I'm dragging the mouse over it.

Basically, I'm drawing free-form lines on a custom panel with the following handlers attached:

```
MouseInputAdapter mia = new MouseInputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(_app_split_right_buttons_radioInkBtn.isSelected()) {
                    _app_split_right_journal.StartLine();
                    _app_split_right_journal.AddLineSegment(e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
                _app_split_right_journal.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if(_app_split_right_buttons_radioInkBtn.isSelected()) {
                    _app_split_right_journal.AddLineSegment(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    _app_split_right_journal.EndLine();
                }
                _app_split_right_journal.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if(_app_split_right_buttons_radioInkBtn.isSelected()) {
                    _app_split_right_journal.AddLineSegment(e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
                _app_split_right_journal.repaint();
            }
        };
        _app_split_right_journal.addMouseListener(mia);
        _app_split_right_journal.addMouseMotionListener(mia);
```

However, I can't seem to get it to repaint while I'm dragging the mouse, only after I release it (the line draws correctly). Oddly enough, if in the middle of my drag, I right-click, the line will suddenly start drawing as I'm dragging.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: For clarity, the StartLine()/AddLineSegment()/EndLine() stuff just adds points to an ArrayList of Point objects, and the repaint() function has been overridden to cycle through those points and draw line segments between each. Code below:

```
public void DrawShapes(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        for(Geometry.Shape shape : _shapeList) {
            if(shape instanceof Geometry.Line) {
                ArrayList<Point> points = ((Line) shape).GetPointList();
                Point p1 = points.get(0);
                for(int i=1; i<points.size(); i++) {
                    Point p = points.get(i);
                    g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p.x, p.y);
                    p1 = p;
                }
            }
}
```

Edit: Figured it out. It's because I was cycling through the list of lines, but I forgot that I don't add the line I'm currently drawing to that list until I release the mouse and call EndLine(). I had to put separate code in the repaint() method to paint the shape I'm currently in the middle of drawing. Code added to repaint():

```
if(_currentShape instanceof Geometry.Line) {
            ArrayList<Point> points = ((Line)_currentShape).GetPointList();
            Point p1 = points.get(0);
            for(int i=1; i<points.size(); i++) {
                Point p = points.get(i);
                g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p.x, p.y);
                p1 = p;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try calling repaint on the parent container as well/instead

Answer (score 5):

This is an example I did for another question, but it uses a mouse drag to draw lines onto the component...

```
public class PaintingExample {

    private BufferedImage bImage;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private int xClicked = 0;
    private int yClicked = 0;
    private int xDragged = 0;
    private int yDragged = 0;
    private MouseAdapter mouseListener =
        new MouseAdapter() {
            private boolean paint = false;
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

                xClicked = me.getX();
                yClicked = me.getY();
                xDragged = xClicked;
                yDragged = yClicked;

                paint = true;

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                xClicked = -1;
                xClicked = -1;
                xDragged = -1;
                yDragged = -1;

                paint = false;

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

                if (paint) {

                    xClicked = xDragged;
                    yClicked = yDragged;

                    xDragged = me.getX();
                    yDragged = me.getY();

                    xDragged = me.getX();
                    yDragged = me.getY();

                    Graphics2D g2 = bImage.createGraphics();
                    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g2.drawLine(xClicked, yClicked, xDragged, yDragged);
                    g2.dispose();
                    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bImage));

                    me.getComponent().repaint();

                }

            }
        };

    public PaintingExample() {
        try {
            bImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                            "http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/"
                            + "gaganisonline/images/planetbackground.jpg"));
            image = new ImageIcon(bImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting on Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
        imageLabel.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);

        contentPane.add(imageLabel);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PaintingExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are killin' it! Seen so many helpful answers from you on this topic

Comment: Anyone want to point out the reason for the downvote? I'd like to learn what it might be that you've seen is wrong with the answer please